# MVC 5 Alternative to RenderAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mono

Is there an alternative way to achieve the same result as

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Builder", "Question"); }
```

but with different syntax. E.G. standard ASPX or HTML.

Mono currently does not support any `Action` related Html helpers. In other words, the mono implementation of RouteCollection.cs is missing `AppendtailingSlash` property. (Currently fixed in mono 4.3 but waiting for a release)

Is there perhaps other syntax or perhaps HTML I can use to render an action in a different controller?

My reason for asking is because we are currently using `<a></a>` html tags for ActionLinks due to the same reason. So thought there might be a different approach for `RenderAction` too.

If there is a different way I can achieve the same result, can you please post an answer.

Comment: Are you sure Mono doesn't support it? It does seem to exist https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/ChildActionExtensions.cs

Comment: That is the master branch. If you check the 4.0.3.20 branch it's not there. As I said the fix is there but not released yet. If you go to mono website and go to the tar download section. You will see in the releases its not there. It is in the nightly but those repositories are untested

Comment: The latest release is not necessarily built from the latest master. I wish it was.

Comment: Yes but with that you can copy the code into your own code. Either extending the Html class or create your own stativ helper class.

Comment: The mvc framework won't point to the extended class. We will have to rewrite a lot of the mvc functionality. Unless you can perhaps point me into the right direction

Comment: The error is far down deep in the framework. Overriding the `Action` static call probably won't fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Mono does now indeed support `Action` but it is limited. For Example you can not use `@Url.Action` in Javascript, it will not work correctly. But other than that the support it there. So no need for an alternative.